# What is a better solution for controlling actuators than Arduino?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My problem is that any AVR is too slow for an update rate close to the MHz rate. So it eliminates the possibility of using high precision hardware like some encoders that run at 12MHz, some IMUs go up to 1MHz, High precision Servo Motors. All the cool stuff has extremely high update rates so I would like to know if someone know a good FPGA or PIC board that is easy to implement with ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268171/what-is-a-better-solution-for-controlling-actuators-than-arduino????/) by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2017-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use [rosserial_mbed](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_mbed). It is a client library similar to rosserial_arduino that will help you to easily interface your hardware with mbed compatible micro-controllers. You can find a tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_mbed/Tutorials).

If you are interested in development boards like Arduino, you can use the [ST Nucleo](http://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32-mcu-nucleo.html?querycriteria=productId=LN1847) development boards that are powerful, cheap compared to Arduino and with a consequent community.

It seems that most of the solutions are based on ARM. If you  want to use a PIC or other architectures, you need to implement the [rosserial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial) protocol on the micro-controller.

---

Originally posted by [jeanpolochon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27330/jeanpolochon/) with karma: 140 on 2017-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on 2017-08-07**:
I really liked your answer. I need to explore a little bit this option. It seems that they are all based on ARM Cortex-M series.I will play with it and see.
What I like in Development boards is not going into low level all the time, which makes prototyping faster.
I am open to other suggestion too.